# Javascript : can we reuse inner function to acces both global and local

Tags: javascript

```
var teamName ="studio";
var otherTeamName ={
    teamName :'factory',
    getTeamName : function(){
        alert(this.teamName);
    }
};
window.otherTeamName.getTeamName();// alerts factory
```

Is there any way to get the **`studio`**? by using the same **`getTeamName`** function.(i.e i know, removing **`this`** will fetch studio.) without removing the this?

Comment: you can try using a setter..

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. There are two ways:

1. use `call`: `otherTeamName.getTeamName.call(window)`
2. copy reference:

   ```js
   var getTeamName = otherTeamName.getTeamName;
   getTeamName(); // alerts studio
   ```

`call()` is not supported by older browsers, the second solution works everywhere.

```js
var teamName = "studio";

var otherTeamName = {
    teamName: 'factory',
    getTeamName: function() {
        alert(this.teamName);
    }
};
otherTeamName.getTeamName(); // alerts factory

var getTeamName = otherTeamName.getTeamName;
getTeamName(); // alerts studio
```

Comment: The second option is nice. Only one remark: call is supported well enough, I don't think it makes sense to talk about support of it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can still use the same `getTeamName` method by changing context function is executed in:

```js
var teamName = "studio";
var otherTeamName = {
    teamName: 'factory',
    getTeamName: function() {
        alert(this.teamName);
    }
};

otherTeamName.getTeamName.call(window);
```

By using [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) you make `this` point to `window` instead of 
`otherTeamName` object.

**UPD.** However, this will only work if `teamName` is global variable. If not, check Quentin's answer.

Comment: And when the code snippet is not in the global scope it won't work.

Comment: @Vohuman Yes, you are right, something for OP to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No. It isn't a property of the object, so you can't access it as if it was.

Longer answer: You could replace the `teamName` property with a [getter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) that returned the value of the variable … but that would be an unintuitive approach to whatever the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
otherTeamName.getTeamName.call(this)
```

this here refers to the window

Answer (score 0):

```
// The good:
otherTeamName.getTeamName.call(this);
otherTeamName.getTeamName.apply(this);

// The okayish:
var f = otherTeamName.getTeamName; f();
otherTeamName.getTeamName.bind(this)();

// The bad:
((f) => f)(otherTeamName.getTeamName)();
(function(f) {f()})(otherTeamName.getTeamName)

// The ugly:
eval(otherTeamName.getTeamName)();
eval("(" + otherTeamName.getTeamName + ")()");
new Function("(" + otherTeamName.getTeamName + ")()")();
```